# Application Struck on Launch Screen when using Singleton Class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Application Manager As Singleton class throughout project. In Appdelegate i set tabbarviewcontroller (that is rootviewcontroller in storyboard ) to the applicationManger mainviewcontroller.

When I run application it gets struck on launch screen although the control goes to the applicationManager functions which can be observed by using break Points... Please help !!!

In AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

      [[ApplicationManager sharedService] setMainViewController:(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController];

    return YES;
}
```

ApplicationManager.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ApplicationManager : NSObject<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *imgView;
}

@property (nonatomic,weak) UITabBarController *mainViewController;
```

ApplicationManager.m

```
@implementation ApplicationManager

@synthesize mainViewController = _mainViewController;

+ (void)load
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sharedService) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (ApplicationManager *)init {


    if (self != nil) {
        self = [super init];

        self.exceptionErrorMessages = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ErrorMessagesFileName ofType:ErrorMessagesFileType]];


    }
    return self;
}

+ (ApplicationManager *)sharedService {
    @synchronized(self) {
        static ApplicationManager *_service = nil;

        if (_service == nil) {
            _service = [[ApplicationManager alloc] init];
        }
        return _service;
    }
}

- (void)setMainViewController:(UITabBarController *)mainViewController
{

    _mainViewController = mainViewController;
    _mainViewController.delegate = self;
    UITabBarItem *loginItem =  _mainViewController.tabBar.items[3];
    UIImage *unSelectedImage = [[self imageFromString:@"" withColor:[UIColor redColor]]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [[self imageFromString:@"" withColor:[ColorUtility appBlueColor]]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    if ([SharedManager getInstance].isLoggedIn)
    {
        loginItem.title = @"Logout";
        [_mainViewController setSelectedIndex:TabBarTagInspection];
    }
    else
    {
        loginItem.title = @"Login";
        [_mainViewController setSelectedIndex:TabBarTagLogin];
    }

    UITabBarItem *syncItem = _mainViewController.tabBar.items[0];
    syncItem.image = [self imageFromString:@"" withColor:nil];
    UITabBarItem *inspectionItem = _mainViewController.tabBar.items[1];
    inspectionItem.image = [self imageFromString:@"\uE8ac" withColor:nil];
    UITabBarItem *vendorItem = _mainViewController.tabBar.items[2];
    vendorItem.image = [self imageFromString:@"\uE85f" withColor:nil];
    UITabBarItem *materialItem = _mainViewController.tabBar.items[3];
    materialItem.image = [self imageFromString:@"" withColor:nil];


    loginItem.image = unSelectedImage;
    loginItem.selectedImage = selectedImage;
}
```

STORYBOARD ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: Yours singleton implementation is wrong. Try to google how to make it right.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code.  However, your posted issue is caused by never setting the window's `rootViewController`.

Comment: That is not working either... and window's rootViewController will automatically set from storyboard initial view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton implementation of the above code is wrong. static variable should be defined outside the shared function.

```
@implementation ApplicationManager

static ApplicationManager *_service = nil;
```

Shared function was reseting _service variable. May be it is too late but I answered so that It might help some one